# Ubuntu Touch - Missed calls notifications

Tags: ubuntu-touch, notification

When I have a missed call, I receive the missed call notification all ok. However, when I click on the notification, I only have the option to send a text (SMS) back to the person I missed the call off.

A far better idea would be to allow users the option of sending a text or calling the person back from the notifications window.

Is there a setting I can change to do this, so I can call them back from here? I have looked up on this and cannot see anything.

Answer (score 1):

Tapping on the missed calls notification opens two options: "Message" and "Call back". Alternatively you can tap the dialer icon (in red circle). It will take you to the dialer app with the caller's number typed in.
[image: Missed calls notification screenshot]

Comment: I believe this is the intended behaviour. If you're not seeing these options you may report a bug at launchpad.

Comment: ||||When I posted this question I did not see this behavior. However, on retest, I did get the notification shown above. There are two missed call notifications. The first one is when the person calling rings a fre times and then cuts off. This gives the notification as shown above. The secone is then the person calling goes through to your answer machine (but does not leave a message). THis notification is the one I was receiving and which does not give the option to call the person back. This is where the option to call back and/or message is needed.

Comment: The answer you provided above, does not really answer my question as there are more than one way in which the missed call notification works.

Comment: Looks like a legit bug. You might want to report it.